# Unknown error during React + Sanity project

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I'm doing a portfolio website using React with Sanity and counter an error that make the page goes blank. This happen when I tried to fetch data from Sanity. But the console doesn't show that was the cause, instead showing 'Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function' and 'Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined'.

Connect to sanity (.env file used)

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2024-03-01',
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

Fetching data

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion/dist/framer-motion';

import './About.scss';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';

const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setAbouts(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className='head-text'>
        Tanah untuk <span>Dijual</span>
      </h2>
      <div className='app__profiles'>
        {abouts.map((about, index) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: 'tween' }}
            className='app__profile-item'
            key={about.title + index}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
            <h2 className='bold-text' style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              {about.title}
            </h2>
            <h2 className='p-text' style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
              {about.description}
            </h2>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default About;
```

[The two errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erwcj.png)

Does it related with my sanity version?

Comment: Please share more details about your question. Provide code snippets as well where you have implemented this

Comment: Apparently changing my react-script to 5.0.1 solve the issue